# How does mechanical absolute encoder work?

Tags: encoder, mechanical

I want to know more about this kind of encoder, but I can't find any source (other than wikipedia), where I can get more details about it. Can anyone explain or point me to a source where I can read about it?
I want to understand the working principle of mechanical absolute encoder.

Comment: Aren't those pretty much just high-quality and high-linearity potentiometers?

Comment: Yes, they are like potentiometers, but working principle seems to be different than potentiometers that I know. As I read about mechanical absolute encoders, documentation says that there are few brush-type contacts, and I can't understand how they work.

Comment: Google 'absolute encoder tutorial' - lots of links, including youtube

Comment: I don't have a problem understanding what an 'absolute encoder' is, I know about optical, magnetic types, I understand them. But I want to know about MECHANICAL encoder.

Comment: Can you give a link to a typical device?

Comment: http://www.grayhill.com/products/mechanical-encoders/

Comment: Those are just low bit count encoders with detents on the shaft.  For the ultimate cheap and dirty, they can be simple spring loaded wipers running against a coded disk.  Most of that type are still optical though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of like thumbwheel switches.

[Customizing Digital Thumbwheel Switches](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/155703/customizing-digital-thumbwheel-switches)

Incremental mechanical encoders are used in computer mice and digital control knobs but these usually only have 3 contacts that resolve A and B quadrature signals.